# Double +inf calculations

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, math

I have a financial equation that gives very large outputs like 10 ^ 800. But for some reason when i do the calculation it gives me and output of +inf. How can I overcome this to perform large calculations without using any library?. The equation and the hypothetical substitutes as follow.

```
 //Values
n = 12.0
r = 95.60
t = 120.2
PMT = 20000.00
```

Code

```
    let commonfactor = pow((1 + (r/n)), (n*t)) // this returns inf
    let denominator = r/n
    let numerator = ((commonfactor) - 1)

    let finalOutput = PMT * (numerator/denominator)
```

Equation
[image: ft]

Comment: +inf mean infinity. seems like you did the calculation wrong. Add your code to question

Comment: Shouldn't this be tagged with some math and algorithm tags since it looks more like something that needs to be solved by re-writing the equation before it can be translated into code rather than a pure programming issue.

Comment: Getting **Cannot convert value of type 'Double' to expected argument type 'Int'** on `let commonfactor = pow((1 + (r/n)), (n*t))`. Did you have such issue?

Comment: The maximum finite value representable in Double is around 10^308. `pow` returns +inf when the result will be greater than that. If you need to calculate the value given inputs as in your post, you may need to find a math library which can represent and calculate values greater than that bound.

Comment: Thats why i asked is there any way to perform this equation without using any library. And ye sits true that max is 10^308. Im just looking a way to solve this equation

Comment: The feature you want is a BigNum and there is no BigNum type in stdlib. Search for any "Swift BigNum" library to see how they're built. You certainly don't need to include a library; you can just write the same code yourself. I'd expect a few hundred lines of code since you need most of the arithmetic operations. Maybe little longer if you want it to be fast, or a bit shorter if you don't care about performance too much.

Comment: @RobNapier  Im aware of BigNum  and BInt. But thats why i mentioned without any libraries

Comment: If you also mean "without a few hundred lines of code," then the answer is no.